# Переключатель страниц

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вопрос конкретно к верстальщикам. Как обычно реализуют подобные блоки (см. скриншот) с количеством страниц?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: pagination - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_pagination.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называется подобный приём "пагинация".

> Пагинация (от лат. pagina — страница) — многозначный термин:
>
> В издательском деле пагинация — порядковая нумерация страниц,
>   обозначаемая колонцифрами, располагаемыми внизу, вверху или сбоку
>   страницы.

Как и прочую упорядоченную информацию, эти данные удобно выводить списком: контейнером будет `ul`, а каждая ссылка на страницы с первой по последнюю включая переходы "вперед" и "назад" будет элементом `li`.
Соответственно, внутри `li` можно располагать ссылки на необходимые страницы через элемент `a` и стилизовать каким угодно образом.

[Примеры создания и настройки от W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_pagination.asp)

Ниже ссылки на базовые решения от известных фреймворков:

[Bootstrap pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-default)
[Foundation pagination](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/pagination.html)